# Use toggles in biblatex `printbibliography`

Tags: biblatex, etoolbox

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@mastersthesis{toto,
author={Toto},
title={My thesis},
year={2009},
school={Paris 129},
keywords={mem}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\newtoggle{display}
\toggletrue{display}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[\iftoggle{display}{keyword=mem}{notkeyword=mem}]
\togglefalse{display}
\printbibliography[\iftoggle{display}{keyword=mem}{notkeyword=mem}]
\end{document}
```

The behavior I would expect is that depending of the value of the toggle `display`, the entries with the keyword `mem` would be displayed or not.

However, all I get is `! Package keyval Error: keyword=mem undefined.` and  `! Package keyval Error: notkeyword=mem undefined.` errors.

Comment: Are you loading package `bibtex` or package `biblatex`?

Comment: `\addbibresource` must be in the preamble

Comment: Yes sorry I corrected my MWE: `biblatex` and `\addbibressource` at the right place.

Comment: Would `\iftoggle{display}{\printbibliography[...]}{\printbibliography[...]}` not be easier?

Comment: The solution proposed by @ChristianHupfer works indeed. But 1° my list of options for that `printibliography` command is long, so it is not very handy to copy/paste it every time I want to change it, and 2° I'd like to understand that error!

Answer (score 4):

You have to expand the optional argument before `\printbibliography` sees it:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mastersthesis{toto,
author={Toto},
title={My thesis},
year={2009},
school={Paris 129},
keywords={mem}
}
@mastersthesis{toto2,
author={Toto},
title={My thesis not mem},
year={2009},
school={Paris 129},
keywords={notmem}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newtoggle{display}
\toggletrue{display}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand
  \printbibliography[\iftoggle{display}{keyword=mem}{notkeyword=mem}]%
}\x

\togglefalse{display}

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand
  \printbibliography[\iftoggle{display}{keyword=mem}{notkeyword=mem}]%
}\x

\end{document}
```

[image]

A friendlier interface can be obtained with `xparse`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mastersthesis{toto,
author={Toto},
title={My thesis},
year={2009},
school={Paris 129},
keywords={mem}
}
@mastersthesis{toto2,
author={Toto},
title={My thesis not mem},
year={2009},
school={Paris 129},
keywords={notmem}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xparse}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newtoggle{display}
\toggletrue{display}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xprintbibliography}{o}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \printbibliography
   }
   {
    \clement_xprintbibliography:x { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \clement_xprintbibliography:n #1
 {
  \printbibliography[#1]
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clement_xprintbibliography:n { x }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\xprintbibliography[\iftoggle{display}{keyword=mem}{notkeyword=mem}]%

\togglefalse{display}

\xprintbibliography[\iftoggle{display}{keyword=mem}{notkeyword=mem}]%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a quite complicated document structure, with imbricated toggles, so I have to spend some time figuring out how to adapt your answer. For some strange reasons, the other options of `xprintbibliography` get eaten in my document (I know that don't happen in your simpler document).

Comment: @Clément Some examples of failure are necessary.

Comment: I know, but I have to make them minimal, and it's quite late where I live (and I spent nearly 4 hours trying to debug that question by myself!).

Comment: @Clément Have a good sleep and let's see it tomorrow. We're in the same time zone. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

For a reason I still do not understand, it is okay to juste let the `keyword`/`notkeyword` be dependent of the toggle.

For the sake of readability, I enclosed the `\iftoggle{display}{keyword}{notkeyword}` as a new command (`etiquette`, which means "label" in french), but this is not mandatory.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@mastersthesis{toto1,
author={Toto},
title={My thesis},
year={2009},
school={Paris 129},
keywords={mem}
}
@mastersthesis{toto2,
author={Toto},
title={My new thesis},
year={2015},
school={Paris 32},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\newtoggle{display}
\toggletrue{display}

\newcommand{\etiquette}{\iftoggle{display}{keyword}{notkeyword}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[\etiquette=mem, title={With mem keyword}]
\togglefalse{display}
\printbibliography[\etiquette=mem, title={With\emph{out} mem keyword}]
\end{document}
```

Compiles without warning, and give the expected :

[image]

---

Surprinsignly, the other way around, i.e.

```
\newcommand{\etiquette}{\iftoggle{display}{mem}{bubu}}
...
\printbibliography[notkeyword=\etiquette, title={Without mem keyword}]
\togglefalse{display}
\printbibliography[notkeyword=\etiquette, title={Without bubu keyword}]
...
```

does not work (no warning, but everything is cited each time).

Comment: The `\iftoggle` tests are not expanded, in my point of view, that's why the keys are incorrectly assigned

Comment: And you have any idea on how to patch this behavior, or what kind of tool I should use?

Comment: I tried for over one hour now, and failed.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'm glad a TeX-champion like you do not succeed either ;) The answer I propose is more a workaround than a real solution, and I'm not fully satisfied with it neither.

Comment: I asked a separate question on this and egreg answered it;-) I am not sure that it will work with `\iftoggle` too.

Comment: I am no TeX-champion at all.

Comment: Maybe, but [you reformulated my question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/228325/34551) in terms much more precises than anything I could have been capable of!